# WoW - Who can add sockets to items?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

For example, Blacksmith [can](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=122632/living-steel-belt-buckle) add a socket to belt. It is only for soulbound belts and only up to 600lvl, but anyway.

What are other possibilities to add sockets to items? How many sockets can be added to one item? Does this forbid additional enchant on item or not? Is it possible for other person gear with lvl>600?

Comment: Are you playing private or live? If your playing private, whats the current expansion your playing?

Comment: I would suggest not answering @r wank as private server falls under piracy or illegal software, and might get this question closed, where it is otherwise a good question.

Comment: @rwank, I'm playing usual:) This would be live, I guess. Warlords of Draenor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blacksmith WAS the only profession capable of adding sockets to gear. The beltbuckle was not limited to the profession so everyone could use it.

In the recent expansion (Warlords of Draenor)they have removed all profession only benefits and enchants. Now sockets have a chance of bonus rolling on any item you find in raids/dungeons. In most cases socket> warforged rolls, since you can get 50/75 of your most valuable stat instead of 10-15 on every stat already on the item.

Comment: So if you rolled the same item with and without a socket, all they stats will be similar (within a random variation, which any 2ndary stats have)?

Comment: @klm123 yes. the socket is an added bonus. the base stats stay the same. But you can get  a warforged item with a socket, so i has more stats than the base version AND a socket ontop aswell